# Configuring Apache WSGI for Flask on Google Compute Engine (Flask Import Error using mod_wsgi)

Tags: python, apache, flask, google-compute-engine, mod-wsgi

I am trying to follow an introductory book/tutorial on Flask, and part of the tutorial requires that you set up both a local development environment, and a production environment on a virtual private server.

**In short, I get an error that looks like a Python import error complaining that it cannot find Flask.**

I have gone through other Flask import error stack overflow posts, to no avail: I do not believe I have a mismatch of mod_wsgi with my python version, and I have inserted what I believe is the Flask directory into the path (about two dozen different ways, nothing worked). I wonder if there's an issue because perhaps Google Compute Engine runs apache as some specific user, whereas Flask is installed to a subfolder of "~", which I believe depends on the username I use when I SSH in--in other words, maybe Apache can't see that folder, or any "user folder"?. I am inexperienced with Linux, so am struggling to narrow down the problem.

**But overall, how do I correct the import error for hello.py when it is being executed through mod_wsgi?**

Many thanks in advance the brave soul daring enough to read on! More detail below, including files/contents, steps to reproduce, etc.

I get a 500 Internal Server Error when I visit the page that should be showing the hello.py app. Consulting the logs shows the following error (I added a few python print statements to get some idea of what's going on):

```
[Mon Jul 03 00:58:21.619295 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4520:tid 

139990843242240] PYTHON SYS.PATH:
[Mon Jul 03 00:58:21.619440 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4520:tid 139990843242240] ['~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/var/www/firstapp', '~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/var/www/firstapp', '~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/var/www/firstapp', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
[Mon Jul 03 00:58:21.619501 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4520:tid 139990843242240] PYTHON VERSION:
[Mon Jul 03 00:58:21.619539 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4520:tid 139990843242240] sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=12, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
[Mon Jul 03 00:58:21.619581 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4520:tid 139990843242240] PYTHON LOCATION OF EXECUTABLE:
[Mon Jul 03 00:58:21.619619 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4520:tid 139990843242240] /usr/bin/python
[Mon Jul 03 00:58:21.619646 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4520:tid 139990843242240] 
[Mon Jul 03 00:58:21.619674 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4520:tid 139990843242240] 
[Mon Jul 03 00:58:21.619806 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4520:tid 139990843242240] [remote 100.38.132.195:60448] mod_wsgi (pid=4520): Target WSGI script '/var/www/firstapp/hello.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Mon Jul 03 00:58:21.619844 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4520:tid 139990843242240] [remote 100.38.132.195:60448] mod_wsgi (pid=4520): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/firstapp/hello.wsgi'.
[Mon Jul 03 00:58:21.619898 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4520:tid 139990843242240] [remote 100.38.132.195:60448] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Mon Jul 03 00:58:21.619952 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4520:tid 139990843242240] [remote 100.38.132.195:60448]   File "/var/www/firstapp/hello.wsgi", line 4, in <module>
[Mon Jul 03 00:58:21.620010 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4520:tid 139990843242240] [remote 100.38.132.195:60448]     from hello import app as application
[Mon Jul 03 00:58:21.620042 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4520:tid 139990843242240] [remote 100.38.132.195:60448]   File "/var/www/firstapp/hello.py", line 10, in <module>
[Mon Jul 03 00:58:21.620082 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4520:tid 139990843242240] [remote 100.38.132.195:60448]     from flask import Flask
[Mon Jul 03 00:58:21.620131 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4520:tid 139990843242240] [remote 100.38.132.195:60448] ImportError: No module named flask
[Mon Jul 03 00:58:40.176748 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4520:tid 139990725629696] PYTHON SYS.PATH:
[Mon Jul 03 00:58:40.176930 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4520:tid 139990725629696] ['~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/var/www/firstapp', '~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/var/www/firstapp', '~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/var/www/firstapp', '~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/var/www/firstapp', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
[Mon Jul 03 00:58:40.176983 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4520:tid 139990725629696] PYTHON VERSION:
[Mon Jul 03 00:58:40.177023 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4520:tid 139990725629696] sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=12, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
[Mon Jul 03 00:58:40.177060 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4520:tid 139990725629696] PYTHON LOCATION OF EXECUTABLE:
[Mon Jul 03 00:58:40.177092 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4520:tid 139990725629696] /usr/bin/python
[Mon Jul 03 00:58:40.177122 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4520:tid 139990725629696] 
[Mon Jul 03 00:58:40.177150 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4520:tid 139990725629696] 
[Mon Jul 03 00:58:40.177327 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4520:tid 139990725629696] [remote 100.38.132.195:63520] mod_wsgi (pid=4520): Target WSGI script '/var/www/firstapp/hello.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Mon Jul 03 00:58:40.177380 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4520:tid 139990725629696] [remote 100.38.132.195:63520] mod_wsgi (pid=4520): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/firstapp/hello.wsgi'.
[Mon Jul 03 00:58:40.177430 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4520:tid 139990725629696] [remote 100.38.132.195:63520] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Mon Jul 03 00:58:40.177490 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4520:tid 139990725629696] [remote 100.38.132.195:63520]   File "/var/www/firstapp/hello.wsgi", line 4, in <module>
[Mon Jul 03 00:58:40.177559 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4520:tid 139990725629696] [remote 100.38.132.195:63520]     from hello import app as application
[Mon Jul 03 00:58:40.177604 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4520:tid 139990725629696] [remote 100.38.132.195:63520]   File "/var/www/firstapp/hello.py", line 10, in <module>
[Mon Jul 03 00:58:40.177660 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4520:tid 139990725629696] [remote 100.38.132.195:63520]     from flask import Flask
[Mon Jul 03 00:58:40.177709 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4520:tid 139990725629696] [remote 100.38.132.195:63520] ImportError: No module named flask
```

I might be mistaken, but I believe the important part of the error is:

```
ImportError: No module named flask
```

What's odd is that if I run "python hello.py" (see below for the files and contents), there is no flask import error. This tells me that when Apache is using mod_wsgi to execute hello.py, it "forgets" where Flask is. I'm not sure how to tell it where to look. When I verify that Flask is installed, PIP specifies the location where it is installed.

```
alexanderblank@instance-1:/var/www/firstapp$ pip install flask

Requirement already satisfied: flask in /home/alexanderblank/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=0.21 in /home/alexanderblank/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from flask)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=2.0 in /home/alexanderblank/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from flask)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=0.7 in /home/alexanderblank/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from flask)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=2.4 in /home/alexanderblank/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from flask)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in /home/alexanderblank/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Jinja2>=2.4->flask)
```

I tried to "insert" that folder into the Python search path in the WSGI file with:

```
sys.path.insert(0, "~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages")
```

I have detailed the exact steps I took below (server setup, and code files), and have been trying to troubleshoot this for several hours now.

I created a new Ubuntu 16 LTS instance on Google Compute Engine -- I will call this the "VPS" (for virtual private server). I completed the following steps:

(1) SSH into the VPS.
(2) Ran the following commands to install python, pip and flask:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-pip
pip install --user Flask
sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi
```

(3) Tested the configuration by visiting the VPS public IP, and it showed the default Apache2 Ubuntu page (so firewall works, web server appears to be able to serve up the default page).

Then I pulled the Python files that I had created locally using GIT. In /var/www/ I have the following files:

```
instance-1:/var/www$ tree -R
.
├── firstapp
│   ├── hello.py
│   ├── hello.pyc
│   ├── hello.wsgi
│   └── README.md
└── html
    └── index.html
```

In /etc/apache2/sites-available I created a new file called hello.conf

```
├── 000-default.conf
├── default-ssl.conf
└── hello.conf
```

I also took ownership of the /etc/apache2 directory recursively, using:

```
sudo chown -R [my_ssh_username] /etc/apache2
```

Then I told Apache to ignore the old .conf files, and look at hello.conf instead, by running:

```
sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf
sudo a2ensite hello.conf
sudo service apache2 reload
```

This results in a 500 Internal Server error when I visit the public IP address of the VPS. I looked at the log file by running:

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

Oddly, running the file from the SSH shell works as expected (no trouble importing flask):

```
instance-1:/var/www/firstapp$ python hello.py

PYTHON SYS.PATH:
['/var/www/firstapp', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/home/alexanderblank/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
PYTHON VERSION:
sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=12, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
PYTHON LOCATION OF EXECUTABLE:
/usr/bin/python


 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
PYTHON SYS.PATH:
['/var/www/firstapp', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/home/alexanderblank/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
PYTHON VERSION:
sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=12, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
PYTHON LOCATION OF EXECUTABLE:
/usr/bin/python


 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 278-244-316
```

I have included the contents of the important files I made below.

hello.conf

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName example.com

    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/firstapp/hello.wsgi
    WSGIDaemonProcess hello
    <Directory /var/www/firstapp>
        WSGIProcessGroup hello
        WSGIApplicationGroup ${GLOBAL}
         Order deny,allow
         Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

hello.py

```
import sys
print "PYTHON SYS.PATH:"
print sys.path
print "PYTHON VERSION:"
print sys.version_info
print "PYTHON LOCATION OF EXECUTABLE:"
print sys.executable
print "\n"

from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "Hello, World!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True)
```

hello.wsgi

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/var/www/firstapp")
sys.path.insert(0, "~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages")
from hello import app as application
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `~` in a path added to `sys.path.insert()`.

```
sys.path.insert(0, "~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages")
```

If you want to do that use:

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.expanduser("~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages"))
```

For general information on how to setup mod_wsgi with Python virtual environments see:

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html

Comment: Thanks Graham. I'll replace the tilde with an absolute, hard-coded path. Before going down that route, however, do you recommend that I re-install Flask outside of any user folder (so that Apache is not dependent on the home directory of any specific user -- that home folder is arbitrary based on the user I used to SSH onto the VPS)? Or is it generally fine to just point to a specific user folder (and if the user-folder approach is fine, do I need to alter permissions so that mod_wsgi and/or Apache can read/write to the user folder where Flask is located)?

Comment: Following up on Graham's suggestion, I just avoided the issue entirely by installing flask "globally" for lack of a better term. I ran: "sudo -H pip install flask", and all my problems were solved. Clearly, I did not really address the issue of how to point mod_wsgi to the right site-packages directory, if you installed to a user folder, but for a tutorial this workaround is sufficient.

Comment: In general you should avoid installing into the system Python installation because any system packages for Python third party packages may conflict and cause you problems.